# How to change my wp-admin URL?

Tags: wordpress, administration

This is the wrong URL: `http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample2.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

This is the URL that I want to change: `http://example2.com/wp-admin`

Comment: You'd likely receive more answers on our sister [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site, for example [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=change+wp-admin+URL+is%3Aquestion) are some related questions.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to install a plugin named **"All in one WP security"** By  "Tips and Tricks HQ". Then go to the **Brute Force** section and check the **Enable Rename Login Page Feature** checkbox and create another path to your admin access page.

If somebody try to access /wp-admin or /wp-login.php they will get an 404 http status. You can specify the access to the wp-admin, I recommend using something like yourdomain.com/management  (For security do not use webmaster/dashboard/login)

Hope this helps